# How do I get logrotate to obey logrotate.d/uwsgi instead of uwsgi.ini? (Centos 6)

Tags: linux, uwsgi, centos6, logrotate

So it seems setting the maximum log rotate size only works when it's set in uwsgi.ini and not /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi (even though manually testing logrotate using /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi file works, and I see no errors in the cron or logrotate status logs).

```
/var/log/uwsgi/*.log {
daily
missingok
dateext
rotate 7
size 100M
copytruncate
create
compress
}
```

Is there a setting that makes logrotate use the above instead of uwsgi.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue stemmed from SELinux security contexts, where the log directory that was being included in the original logrotate config didn't have the right security permissions. So when I kept doing `ls -al`, I couldn't find anything wrong because it did not show the SELInux security settings for each directory/file. I had to do `ls -Z` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have `copytruncate` which is correct. If you don't then you have to use `postrotate` to stop and restart UWSGI.

As you mentioned manually triggering /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi works, this seems to be a problem with your cron job.

You can put this in `/etc/cron.d/` then check the output of `/tmp/logrotate.status` after it runs (Modify the schedule expression to suit your debugging needs).

```
0 2 * * * root logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi --state /tmp/logrotate.status
```

Check this [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) link if you need help with the schedule expression.

Comment: Above  test works but 'logrotate.d/uwsgi' is still ignored.

Sep 27 01:31:41 my-api anacron[30805]: Job `cron.daily' started
Sep 27 01:31:41 my-api run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[30806]: starting logrotate
Sep 27 01:31:51 my-api run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[30874]: finished logrotate
Sep 27 01:31:51 my-api run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[30806]: starting makewhatis.cron
Sep 27 01:31:51 my-api run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[31032]: finished makewhatis.cron
Sep 27 01:31:51 my-api anacron[30805]: Job `cron.daily' terminated (mailing output)
Sep 27 01:31:51 my-api anacron[30805]: Normal exit (1 job run)

Comment: What really bothers me is that under logrotate.d there are other rotate configs (like nginx - which works normally) along with uwsgi. I don't understand why nginx would work but uwsgi wouldn't- they have identical settings. I also compared permissions and everything. I'm wondering if uwsgi.ini has some overall precedence I can't see.

Comment: What do you mean by above test works but logrotate.d/uwsgi is still ignored? The above test only runs for logrotate.d/uwsgi. Can you show the output of /tmp/logrotate.status? Also would you mind confirming once more that manually triggering it works?

Comment: So just entering the command `logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi --state /tmp/logrotate.status` works and the logrotate.status file shows:

```logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log" 2018-9-28```

but when I put it in /etc/cron.d/ (and schedule it to run), it does not work.

Comment: actually scheduling it works, as long as I use `/usr/sbin/logrotate`.

Comment: But when I change it to actually rotate `15 16 * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi` - that does not work.